# Is there a way to make a frozen program kill itself?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I've recently made a more complex java program for a geometric experiment. It uses a lot of user input, which I can't check at this point. So if the user input is wrong, that may cause the program to freeze. And it isn't really stable anyways. But it's a science program, not a commercial one, so it doesn't matter, but I'd like a convenient way to kill the program if frozen.

Ideally if I click the close button of the `JFrame`, the program exits even if it's frozen.

Is there a way to that?

I could probably use clever exception handling, and maybe I'll do it later, but now it seems quite difficult.

Comment: It seems like the app. is doing a lot of complex processing (a long running task) on the EDT. Doing that will 'freeze' the GUI. Better to do long running tasks using a `SwingWorker` - then the main GUI can remain responsive.

Comment: Wait, are you saying you want a way to click the exit button even though the program is frozen (Because the JFrame freezes too)? Or are you saying that you can click the exit button but that doesn't stop the program?

Comment: "you want a way to click the exit button even though the program is frozen" Yes.
SwingWorker may be a good idea, I don't know what is that, but I'll definitely check it

Comment: SwingWorker was a good idea, but did not work as it should be. After consulting with a firend for 2 hours, we managed to re-structure the program to make it work with `invokeLater`. At least it works know, and I have better understandig of how swing and Graphics works.
I almost did the "killer thread" solution, but I figured out in time the correct one.